# How to remove plugin-specific custom taxonomy terms when plugin is uninstalled?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, terms, uninstallation

I'm trying to write a class that would allow for easy removal of all plugin-related data when the plugin is uninstalled. Specifically, I want it to remove plugin options, custom post type entries, and custom taxonomies and their terms.

What I have written mostly works, but the get_terms function returns an 'invalid_taxonomy' error. Looking into it further, I found that the global $wp_taxonomies does not recognize the custom taxonomies created by the plugin during the uninstall.php process.

So my question is: How does one remove custom taxonomy terms when a plugin is uninstalled?

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/geH1wzRC

Bonus points if you can tell me how to avoid loading this class twice if two plugins contain it. I tried just wrapping the class in `if( !class_exists( 'WP_Plugin_Janitor' ) ) { ... }` but then the class never loaded.

**EDIT** I was able to prevent the class from loading more than once by putting the class in a separate file and wrapping the `include_once` statement in the `if( !class_exists(` statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS: I'm surprised WP doesn't have a built-in function like this. It would give plugin developers a universal way of cleaning up after themselves...

Comment: I think this is a rabbit hole, http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11058

Comment: Yeah...I see what you mean. It looks like there's more to removing a taxonomy than just unsetting it. That said, I still would love to know how to remove taxonomy terms during the uninstall.php process.

Comment: Do you get a fatal error at `get_terms` or does it just not return anything?

Comment: No fatal error. If I do a `var_dump` on $terms, I get this: `object(WP_Error)#246 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } } object(WP_Error)#248 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }`

Comment: I've reported this as a bug, because a plugin should be able to clean up after itself when uninstalled: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23069

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [`register_deactivation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) and/or [`register_uninstall_hooks`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook). That may be why some functions don't work. I'd have to do some testing to be sure, but loading your method directly like `WP_Plugin_Janitor::cleanup( $opt, $cpt, $tax );` seems like a pretty good way to skip over some of the WordPress load sequence or to run things out of order.

As far as loading the class twice, I have an answer, but that is a different question and not really WordPress specific. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm actually putting this in the `uninstall.php` file, so it should behave the same as using `register_uninstall_hook`.

Regarding the class loading twice question, I already resolved that...see my edit above.

Thanks again!